# Can I use any ANE without make classes

Tags: class, actionscript-3, notifications, ane

I make an android app with as3, I write all code in Actions panel without use the class definition, Now I want to add "push notification" ANE, I want to know is it possible to do that without classes? "I don't want to rewrite my code".
(All examples I read are use classes)

Comment: Of course it's possible.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will do it